# Software Serial alternative with AVR (Two Serial/UART ports in atmega328p)

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, uart, atmel

`Arduino` pins can be used as `UART` using the library `SoftwareSerial.h` Is there any alternative for `AVR`?

I need more than one serial port on a `ATmega328P`, but i don't use arduino.

`SoftwareSerial.h` is tied to `Arduino.h` and `Arduino` pins. I do not use `Arduino`, i use `avr-gcc` with `atmega328p` and `atmega8`.

Comment: Sorry my english.

Comment: Sorry, as much as I would like to understand the question, I can't.

Comment: I need more than one serial port on a ATmega328P

Comment: Arduino is AVR. Port it over.

Comment: @Avelino  Transmit only, or receive only, or both?  What baud rate?

Comment: Is there any made library without my having to port it? @NickAlexeev i need transmit and receive. 9600 is good.

Comment: SoftwareSerial.h is tied to Arduino.h and Arduino pins. I do not use Arduino, i use avr-gcc with atmega328p and atmega8.

Answer (score 5):

[AVR274](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an274) describes a single-wire, half-duplex software UART.

[AVR304](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an0941) describes a half-duplex, interrupt-driven software UART, and [AVR305](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an0952) describes a polled alternative.

[AVR307](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an4300) describes implementing a half-duplex UART using a USI.

All code associated with each app note can be downloaded from <s>Atmel's</s> Microchip's website.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the interupt driven software UART. The polled alternative frequently results in corruption, even when just using as simplex output.